# Create Country REGEXP dynamically in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a country table with region like below:

[image]

I would like to write a query so that I can get the below output:

[image]

Is possible to get this output.
If Yes, can please someone help me with the Query(MySQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
    Region,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Country ORDER BY Country SEPARATOR '|') AS Countries
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Region;
```

Comment: Awesome Tim.. Thanks a lot :)